# networkx draw graph deprecated message

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I am trying to draw a graph networkx using python 3.6 with Jupyter notebook and the network package with anaconda. But the graph is not drawing per the documentation, I am just getting a deprecated message.

CODE:

```
import networkx as nx
import csv
import matplotlib as plt

G = nx.read_pajek('Hi-tech.net')

nx.draw(G)
```

MESSAGE:

> MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: pyplot.hold is deprecated.
>       Future behavior will be consistent with the long-time default:
>       plot commands add elements without first clearing the
>       Axes and/or Figure.

```
b = plt.ishold()
```

Future behavior will be consistent with the long-time default:
    plot commands add elements without first clearing the
    Axes and/or Figure.

```
plt.hold(b)
```

> warnings.warn("axes.hold is deprecated, will be removed in 3.0")

Comment: did you manage to fix this as mine is doing the same

Comment: I went into the networkx code and placed a # in front of the lines with '.hold()'. The error message should tell you which line is causing the problem but a search will find them all. Has not given me any problems since then.

Answer (score 34):

To avoid this warning, I just simply replace

```
nx.draw(G)
```

by

```
nx.draw_networkx(G)
```

My Python is 3.4, Jupyter '1.0.0' and networkx '1.11'.

Comment: Better, but I still get "MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The is_string_like function was deprecated in version 2.1."

Comment: nice, that way you get node labels which were missing from the `nx.draw(G)` render

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get rid of the message by going into the networkx library and simply placing # in front of the lines which produced the error.

I would infer the .hold() function is no longer necessary, nor does it need ot be replaced

Answer (score 3):

I could get nx.draw(G) to work by adding the following line of command:

%matplotlib inline

Comment: This worked for me 
`G = G=nx.from_numpy_matrix(network)
%matplotlib inline
nx.draw_networkx(G)`

Answer (score 2):

As error suggest ... I change nx_pylab.py at 611

```
#       if cb.is_numlike(alpha):
        if isinstance(alpha,numbers.Number):
```

Answer (score 0):

I just commented out the **line 365** of file `__init__.py` in Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook which reads

```
@deprecated('3.0', 'isinstance(..., numbers.Number)')
```